# Validate 3rd party transactions on Bitcoin-qt debug window

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-verification, bitcoin-qt-setup

Is there a way to validate a random transaction via transaction ID on the debug window? Imagine I want to validate a transaction between 2 wallets I don't control.

I believe its possible to check if such a transaction exists on the mempool "getmempoolentry" but can I also check the confirmations without having to decode a whole block like with "getrawtransaction"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

Once you have your node up and running, make sure you synced with `txindex` enabled. If you already synced without it, you need to reindex with `txindex=1` in your `bitcoin.conf` file. Restart and wait a couple of hours.

Once its re-synced, open the debug console and type:

```
getrawtransaction "TxID" true
```

Example:

```
getrawtransaction "bf585491b06630a94e06798fdfdf1809cc64741cd5bc0d41a50e69ba5b8ddbc5" true
```

This will return a decoded raw transaction like this:

```
{
  "txid": "bf585491b06630a94e06798fdfdf1809cc64741cd5bc0d41a50e69ba5b8ddbc5",
  "hash": "bf585491b06630a94e06798fdfdf1809cc64741cd5bc0d41a50e69ba5b8ddbc5",
  "version": 1,
  "size": 225,
  "vsize": 225,
  "weight": 900,
  "locktime": 559545,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "089fd283bc8e012eaa0203ebc40bb1b8888b2f0d0f0bac6664b26b250b15847c",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "304402206163b24284d24e03dc650a86e93d5dbec2dc7d66d4bf71f94ab03b147994160202202a236c07ff469ab2fa8aa2c416a467ad8845c2b5697c18ddabbda31ae7e6289e[ALL] 03e35ef46f9517547c2005c1c941c7651ecf59b44625d1239b78cc01eb2be7a72b",
        "hex": "47304402206163b24284d24e03dc650a86e93d5dbec2dc7d66d4bf71f94ab03b147994160202202a236c07ff469ab2fa8aa2c416a467ad8845c2b5697c18ddabbda31ae7e6289e012103e35ef46f9517547c2005c1c941c7651ecf59b44625d1239b78cc01eb2be7a72b"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967293
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.11233558,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 48167b6d7c9ae260d2f1c494705f9557c89bc3c7 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a91448167b6d7c9ae260d2f1c494705f9557c89bc3c788ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "17aAau6cUvT6WCWkwGWHiTqvsVKHfZowW5"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.25392682,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 c109fb3bab724bda053409ca9230f3a0f750aa22 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914c109fb3bab724bda053409ca9230f3a0f750aa2288ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "1JbhNYR96VG7Do6UZjrnrt3KaXrrrZzJ6i"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "hex": "01000000017c84150b256bb26466ac0b0f0d2f8b88b8b10bc4eb0302aa2e018ebc83d29f08000000006a47304402206163b24284d24e03dc650a86e93d5dbec2dc7d66d4bf71f94ab03b147994160202202a236c07ff469ab2fa8aa2c416a467ad8845c2b5697c18ddabbda31ae7e6289e012103e35ef46f9517547c2005c1c941c7651ecf59b44625d1239b78cc01eb2be7a72bfdffffff021669ab00000000001976a91448167b6d7c9ae260d2f1c494705f9557c89bc3c788ac2a768301000000001976a914c109fb3bab724bda053409ca9230f3a0f750aa2288acb9890800",
  "blockhash": "00000000000000000023c227de45c3eb30b0f9727da4fee7b6e22b66c5d2b9da",
  "confirmations": 5,
  "time": 1548119868,
  "blocktime": 1548119868
}
```

Here you can verify confirmations of the transaction if you're checking for transactions from a third party to a cold wallet without having to trust online block explorers.

Comment: Useful link http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/getrawtransaction